# file substitution based on word matching

Tags: bash, awk, sed

i have a file say test.sh which contains the following details

```
    check_interval                  1
    retry_interval                  1
    event_handler_enabled           1
```

i want to replace `event_handler_enabled           1` line by `event_handler_enabled           0`

Kindly help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed -i "s/\(event_handler_enabled.*\)1/\10/" test.sh`

---

Let's see what did `sed` do:

1. First, it found the line that you want to change. The line starts with `event_handler_enabled`(actually it doesn't care how many spaces before).
2. And then, it found the `1`: (`\(event_handler_enabled.*\)1`)
3. Finally, it change the `1` to `0`.

Done.

P.S. As the *back references*, it means that `sed` will find all the characters behind the `event_handler_enabled` and put them in the right place :)

Comment: You may want to explain that you are using *back references* to preserve the unchanging part of the text so the OP can read more about their use should he need to familiarize himself further with the topic.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Lol as if OP cares, look at the effort they put into their question.

Comment: @123 I agree with you. LOL

Comment: While the OP put nothing into it, and probably why it got down voted, nonetheless there are some of us who do appreciate the explanation, thanks! BTW The answers are not just for the OP, they are for everyone it might help in the future too.

Comment: hi wrfly, thanks for your help. but now when i am trying to move back event_handler_enabled           0 line by event_handler_enabled           1 with the above code, its replacing as  event_handler_enabled           01. what i am looking for is event_handler_enabled           1. Any thoughts

Comment: @gosataiani just exchange the order of step2 and step3 like that: `sed -i "s/\(event_handler_enabled.*\)0/\11/" test.sh`